# Is there a test account for Instagram

Tags: api, instagram

Facebook provides developers with a test account for testing purpose, does Instagram provide any test account similar to what Facebook provides?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instagram does not provide test accounts in the same sense Facebook does.

<strike>Instagram provides an [API Console](https://apigee.com/console/instagram) (powered by [Apigee](https://apigee.com/about/)) to test your API calls. For calls requiring an authenticated user you would need to use an existing Instagram account.</strike>

**UPDATE**
Instagram now provides a Sandbox mode for all new applications.

From Instagram

> Apps created on or after Nov 17, 2015 can take advantage of Sandbox mode right away. Apps created before this date will only be able to use Sandbox mode after June 1, 2016, but can still start submitting for review. On June 1, 2016 any app that has not been reviewed and approved will be set to sandbox mode.

More info in the [Instagram docs](https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/).

Comment: FWIW This Apigee product has been broken for months now, ever since IG switched to the new sandbox mode

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Facebook test user, Login on Facebook and then sign up with Facebook test user on Instagram.com
This works for me!

Comment: Instagram asks a phone number than blocks me when I try to log in to Instagram by using that test user.

Comment: @Luke have you found any way to achieve it?