# Apple App Review: Demo Account for Instagram?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, instagram

I submitted an app for review, and it was rejected. In the message they sent me, they wanted a demo account to log into the app with.

My app is accessed solely through an instagram login. According to the following link, Instagram doesn't provide test account.

[Is there a test account for Instagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529463/is-there-a-test-account-for-instagram)

What should I do? Should I tell Apple that it's instagram? Should I try and make another real account on instagram dedicated for testing and give them that?

Here is what Apple sent me:

We began the review of your app but are not able to continue because we need a demo account to fully assess your app features.

Specifically, provide a demo account that will allow us to continue the full review.

Please provide demo account details, including passwords, in the App Review Information section for your app in iTunes Connect. Please ensure that the information you provide includes any data necessary to demonstrate the functionality of your app features.

Comment: If it's only for reviewing purposes, why not create a "test" account manually and provide that to Apple?

Answer (score 1):

I went through the same thing. They can't login and review your app without an Instagram account, so create an account for them and jot the username/password to it in the "Demo Account" or "Notes" section.

As per Apple:

> To provide demo account information:

- Log in to iTunes Connect
- Click on “My Apps”
- Select your app
- Click on “Prerelease”
- Click the build number that you are submitting for review
- Scroll down to the “Beta App Review Information” section
- Provide information in “Demo Account” and/or “Notes” as appropriate
- Click Save
- Click “Submit For Beta App Review”

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be the only way to do this. I wouldn't be surprised if it violates Instagram terms of service in some way.